# Launch Twitter using device’s browser, not launch Twitter app on iOS device

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, inappbrowser

I have an ionic 3 app that needs to launch my company’s Twitter page in the device’s browser. The Twitter link is like : https://www.twitter.com/mycompany.

When I add this link to my page, the behavior is like this:

- If there is no Twitter app installed on the device, the ionic app
  will launch the device browser with the Twitter url above.
- If the Twitter app has been installed on the device, the ionic app will
  launch the Twitter app, and users have to log in to use the Twitter
  app.

This happens on iOS only, even when using InAppBrowser plugin.

Is there any way to always launch the link using the device’s browsers, even when the Twitter app has been installed? It really annoys when users have to create an account and log in to Twitter app just to view my company’s Twitter page.

Thanks.

Comment: Try giving URL using Ionic Themeable browser: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/themeable-browser/

Comment: Not sure if it's a good idea to use a plug-in that is currently out of maintenance. I think I should look for other alternatives instead of using this one.